# Xamarin Forms ListView inside TabbedPage not update using ObservableCollection

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, tabbedpage

The `ListView` of my `XAML` file is being filled with a `ViewModel` that has an `ObservableCollection` from service but the `ListView` is not updating the information. I already check that the service is returning the correct information.

**XML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="DashboardDetailsList" 
            SelectionMode="None" 
            HasUnevenRows="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsList}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            SeparatorVisibility="None">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
              ...
              ...
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Dashboard> DetailsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dashboard>();
//API Call
details = await _clientAPI.getDashboardDetails(id);
if (details != null)
{
    DetailsList.Clear();
    foreach (var item in details)
    {
        DetailsList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it a raised Property, Using InotifyPropertyChanged()

Comment: When you set ViewModel as BindingContext of Page?

Converting DetailsList to full property and invoke OnPropertyChanged will be safer code.

Comment: Hello, @enish please give me sample code.

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the entire XAML + its Code Behind? Echoing @enisn - I too have a hunch that you're not setting `ContentPage.BindingContext`, because your ViewModel logic is good and you are correctly binding the `ListView.ItemSource` to the `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this man

```
public ObservableCollection<Dashboard> DetailsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dashboard>();
//API Call
details = await _clientAPI.getDashboardDetails(id);
if (details != null)
{
    DetailsList = details;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry man.. Are you using MVVM?

You need to inform that the variable has been changed.

Like this

```
private ObservableCollection <Dashboard> _detailsList;
public ObservableCollection <Dashboard> DetailsList
{
    get => _detailsList;
    private set => SetProperty (ref _detailsList, value);
}

//API Call
details = await _clientAPI.getDashboardDetails(id);
if (details != null)
{
    DetailsList = details;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. `ObservableCollection.Add` automatically calls `PropertyChanged`. Here's an example showing how to use ObservableCollection in a ViewModel: https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp/blob/a7bc592401fc3b844b43906e0df2eedbbbc0a383/Src/InvestmentDataSampleApp/ViewModels/OpportunitiesViewModel.cs#L53